# Lining up fans in a row

Tags: velocity, air, fan

Im new to this website, and not extremely educated in the world of physics. I have a very basic (mostly high school, some college) understanding of physics. That being said, I work for the fire department and we use fans to pressurize a house to force smoke to exit in the direction of our choosing. This is done through proper placement of a fan, coupled with predetermined exit "holes".

Now, to my question. It has been a common strategy to place 1 fan behind another fan to increase, air volume being moved(I'm guessing). Is that really what is happening? Also, how much more (CFM?) is gained through using a second fan? 50%, 100%?

Fan Specs: 16" Blade, 3500 RPMs, 10,300 CFM
Assume 1 is setup 5' behind the other. Would it be more effective closer, or further away?

*I know Ive asked a lot of questions at once, but any educational feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is more of an engineering question than a physics based one, so you could try the engineering site if you don't get an answer here. Having said that, engineering-wise, you might be interested in the efficiency of a scaled up version of the same twin blade/propeller approach, the Cessna Skymaster: http://bit.ly/1MG2LMI. Best of luck with it anyway.

Comment: Seems to me that this is really a fluid-flow question (does driving an air flow with in-line sources increase airflow or not).

Comment: This is a hard question to answer. On one hand, two fans in parallel have twice the effective blade area to push air. On the other hand, two fans in series can presumably increase the flow rate. The question is which is larger. For the parallel case, air flow  would be simply double. For the series case, it gets more complicated. The motor can only spin the blades so fast and the blades become less efficient at imparting momentum to the air at higher speeds. There are many variables, but my hunch would be that parallel fans move more air.